# sql datetime formatting

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, datetime

I need two columns in a table in the following manner:

```
OverallTime | ElapsedTime

10          | 3:12:30
```

So 10 would be a number of days and 3:12:30 is 3 days 12 hours 30 mins.
I would then need to calculate `TimeLeft` which would be

```
OverallTime - ElapsedTime
```

What is the correcy datatype that can represent this in a sql DB?

This for SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Date formatting may differ between various SQL flavors.

Comment: Assuming SQL-Server: Use the datetime datatype, and use the datepart() function to pull it apart, as needed.

Comment: what do you mean by _I need two columns in a table_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sql-Server: `OverallTime = days` and `ElapsedTime = 'days:hours:minutes'`

```
declare @d datetime= getdate()

select OverallTime, 
       OverallTime + ':' + convert(varchar(5), @d, 108) ElapsedTime
from (
  select right(convert(varchar(8), @d, 112),2) OverallTime
  ) x
```

[DEMO 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10550)

```
| OVERALLTIME | ELAPSEDTIME |
-----------------------------
|          07 |    07:17:32 |
```

If you mean your date is as shown and need to find `OverallTime - ElapsedTime` then try (replace `@ot` and `@et` with column names);

```
declare @ot int = 10, @et varchar(10) = '3:12:30'

select datediff(minute,time, OverallTime-days) [OverallTime - ElapsedTime]
from (
select  @ot OverallTime, convert(int,left(@et,charindex(':',@et,1)-1)) days,
             right(@et, len(@et) - charindex(':',@et,1)) + ':00' time
  ) x
```

[DEMO 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10570)

```
| OVERALLTIME - ELAPSEDTIME |
-----------------------------
|                      9330 |
```

Comment: I think he also wants to Calculate `TimeLeft` between `OverallTime` and `elapsedTime` columns

Comment: @rs. User has disappeared, Given both answers.